# SwiftUI list deletion

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am facing problem, where i cannot bind Object properly in swiftUI. what I want to do is animate when user tap deletion.

```
 ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
HStack{
    VStack{
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            ForEach(viewModel.cards) { card in
                let deleteAction: (Int) -> Void = { index in
                    withAnimation {
                        viewModel.deleteCard(at: index) // this is where i want to animate changes
                    }
                }
                StatusCardView(cardViewModel: card, editMode: $editMode, shrinked: $shrinked, scale: $scaleFactor, onDelete: deleteAction)
                    .animation(.spring(), value: viewModel.cards)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 1, height: 1)
        Spacer()
    }
    Spacer()
}
```

}

viewModel:

```
    class BubblesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var cards = [CardViewModel]() // it is filled in constructor (not important right now)


        func deleteCard(at index: Int) {
           cards.removeAll(where: {index == $0.index})
            freeCards = cards
            cards.removeAll()
            layoutCards()
        }
}
```

StatusCardView:

```
struct StatusCardView: View {
    ...
    var onDeleteClosure: ((Int) -> Void)

init(cardViewModel: CardViewModel, editMode: Binding<Bool>, shrinked: Binding<Bool>, scale: Binding<CGFloat>, onDelete: @escaping ((Int) -> Void)) {
    ...
    self.onDeleteClosure = onDelete
}

var body: some View {
    
    ZStack {
        ...

                    ZStack {
                        if editMode {
                            
                            Text("-")
                                .font(type.titleFont)
                                .frame(width: 15, height: 15, alignment: .center)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .background(Color.Card.foregroundOutline)
                                .cornerRadius(50)
                                .opacity(editMode ? 1 : 0)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    onDeleteClosure(model.index!) // closure is called here to move logic to ViewModel
                                }
                        } 
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
            }

        }

    }

}
```

}

when I click delete nothing happens. animation is performed only on scroll. Any ideas what seems to be a problem ? edit: I updated post and added code for StatusCardView

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: But the code you have written inside the `action` of a `Button` or an `onTapGesture`

Comment: sorry, i updated the post

Comment: Remove the object and make your cards an @ State. Load the cards in an onAppear. Move the delete func into the View data struct.

Comment: I really want to keep MVVM sctructure